# Why I cannot to choose some parts as breakpoint in the Keil?

Tags: debugging, keil

Why I cannot to choose some parts as breakpoint in the Keil? please consider to these pictures:

[image: figure1]

[image: figure2]

If you consider to some parts that I determined, you will know that I cannot to select those as a breakpoint. Why? some of them are function. that's odd to me.

**Note** that we can choose some parts that are determined with a gray square at the left but if you consider the parts that I determined don't have it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because those lines were optimized out and not compiled into actual instructions. No machine instruction means nothing to break on. If you take a look into the disassembly window, you can see there is no assembly code associated with them.

Comment: +1 and thanks to you and slap to my face! I don't know why I had not considered to this!

Comment: If you really want to break on those lines, or close to them you should add a __nop(); intrinsic, which generates a NOP instruction that you can set a breakpoint on.

Answer (score 1):

Select optimization method -> default (Options for target-> C/C++(AC6)-> Optimisation).
It helped me